# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to retrieve properties

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to get specific properties (e.g. `skills`, `aboutMe`, `responsibilities`) via `/v1.0/users/{id}?$select=skills`

I get following error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": "Zugriff verweigert. Sie haben keine Berechtigung, diesen Vorgang auszuführen oder auf diese Ressource zuzugreifen.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "8a87ee26-b066-42fe-8458-1db74387a47b",
            "date": "2018-02-21T15:23:30"
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to fetch properties like 'surname', 'mail' etc., no problem occurs and I retrieve the desired data.

I get my token via ADAL4J:

```java
service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); 
context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service); 
result = context.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", 
  new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, SECRET), null).get();
String token = result.getAccessToken();
```

Do you know how to set the scope here?

Tried to get token via Postman request and scope
`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` but got the same result.

Is there any other scope which I should use instead of `.default`?

Note: I followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds).

Comment: What scopes have you requested?

Comment: I updated my post regarding your scope question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the app permissions in the meantime, so I had to redo the request to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenant]/adminconsent?client_id=[client-id]&state=12345&redirect_uri=[redirect-uri]`

After accepting the new permissions by an admin, I was able to access the other user properties.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth flow you are using is the Client Credentials grant. Client Credentials are different from traditional OAuth grants in that there isn't a user authenticating. Since there isn't a "User", there also isn't an opportunity to obtain consent for your scopes from the user (User Consent). This leaves you with only one option, obtaining consent from an Admin (Admin Consent). In other words, you **always** need Admin Consent when using Client Credentials.

I wrote an article outlining the differences between User and Admin consent that might help explain what is going on here: [Understanding the difference between User and Admin Consent](http://%20http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-user-vs-admin/).